# CanDeactive Guard: How to reset active class when routing by router.navigateByUrl()

Tags: angular

I'm using a CanDeactivate Guard to prompt a user for unsaved changes; it works great. However, the nav link I pressed to activate the Guard is still selected. How can I reset it to the previous link if the user stays on the page?

I am not using *routerLink* and so I cannot use *routerLinkActive* -- which is the easiest solution. I am using *router.navigateByUrl()* because of the amount of processing I'm doing behind the scenes.

Here's the expression I use to set the active property:

```
    [ngClass]="{
      'nav__active': linkOption.name === menuOptionSelected?.name
    }"
```

When the user clicks on a new link there is a click handler that sets the new *menuOptionSelected*. How can I add an expression to my *ngClass* to wait for the result of the *CanDeactivateGuard*?

Comment: I think you should use angular's built-in [RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive) directive. It automatically detects if link is active and sets a css class to it.

Comment: That means that I'd have to use "routerLink" and I just do too much processing behind the scenes on click of a nav item. I'm using router.navigateByUrl -- which is also a valid option. I've updated my post to make that clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone else runs across this issue. *router.navigateByUrl* returns a Promise saying whether or not the navigation succeeded. In the case where the guard returns false, the navigation fails. You can do s/thing like this where the selected category is only set (and the applicable styles are applied) when the routing succeeds:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(categorySelectedUrl).then((success) => {
    if (success === false) {
    } else {
      this.categorySelected = category;
    }
  });
```